# count how many times is method called

Tags: java, methods

How can I count how many times is dependency.startService(); method call? Different Services are calling this method and I don't want to get how many time did everyone call that method but single Service. I should get this output :

```
My name is Service B and I'm depending on Service A
My name is Service C and I'm depending on Service A
My name is Service D and I'm depending on Service B

***Service Service C lets start!***
   1

***Service Service D lets start!***
   2
```

Actually this number should mean how many services these two are depending on.
Do you have any ideas on how can I do this?
I have tried and I can only get a global number of calling that method which is 3.

Here is my code:

```
 ManagerService.java
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

    public class ManagerService
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
        {
            //Creating Services
            Service serviceA = new Service("Service A", "Thread A");
            Service serviceB = new Service("Service B", "Thread B");
            Service serviceC = new Service("Service C", "Thread C");
            Service serviceD = new Service("Service D", "Thread D");

            serviceB.dependesOn(serviceA);
            serviceC.dependesOn(serviceA);
            serviceD.dependesOn(serviceB);    

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("***Service " + serviceC.serviceName +" lets start!***");
            serviceC.startService();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("***Service " + serviceD.serviceName +" lets start!***");
            serviceD.startService();

        }
    }

and 
Service.java

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Service
{
    public String serviceName;
    public String threadName;
    private boolean onOrOff = false;
    public List <Service> dependentServicesOn = new ArrayList <Service>();
    public CountDownLatch startSignal;
    private Integer counter = 0;
    public Service(String service_name, String thread_name)
    {
        this.serviceName = service_name;
        this.threadName = thread_name;
    }

    public void dependesOn(Service s) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("My name is " + serviceName +" and i'm depending on " + s.serviceName);
        dependentServicesOn.add(s);   
    }

    public Service startService() throws InterruptedException
    {
        for(Service dependency : dependentServicesOn) {
            if(!dependency.isStarted()) {
                dependency.startService();
            }
        }

        startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
       // new Thread(new CreateThread(this,startSignal)).start();
        startSignal.countDown();
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isStarted()
    {
        return onOrOff;
    }

    public void setStarted()
    {
        onOrOff = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: Why do you say "D" should be 2? Is it because D depends on B and then B depends on A? Do you want to traverse the list of dependencies that way?

Comment: @DariusX. yes i'm trying to get that number like that. Do you think that this is not good way?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a variable `count`. For each method call increase the value by one. If you want to access the variable from outside of the class you can set it public static.

So something like this can be done

```
public static long count = 0;

public Service startService() throws InterruptedException
    {
       count++;
       // method tasks
    }
```

When you need to check you can check the `count` variable.

Comment: I did already this and it is not working, i'm getting output like this: ***Service Service C lets start!***
1

***Service Service D lets start!***
1
1

and i should in this Service D 2 not 1 1

Comment: Do it with an AtomicInteger - hackety hack hack. :)

Comment: @njamanjam the above answer is correct, how are you calling the `cout++` in your program?

Comment: @Tdorno i-m using it like this: for(Service dependency : dependentServicesOn) {
            if(!dependency.isStarted()) {
             counter++;
             dependency.startService();
            }  
            System.out.println(counter);
        }

Comment: this is so simple but i just dont know how to get number 2 XD I dont know what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Am new to coding. Can this count concept be used with other languages like javascript and ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Each Service already has a List that stores the "parent" (services on which it is dependent). So, the size of that list is the count of *direct* parents. Since you also want to go further and find indirect dependencies, you can do it by "asking" each parent service how many services it depends upon.

The code would look something like this:

```
public int getCountOfDependencies()
{
   int theCount = 0;

   for (Service nxtService : dependentServicesOn)
   {
      theCount++; //Add one for the "direct parent"

      theCount += nxtService.getCountOfDependencies();  //Also add grand-parents etc.
   }
   return theCount;
}
```

**Warning!** This will not work if a service can be dependent on another service via two or more "paths". For instance, consider this scenario:

```
serviceB.dependesOn(serviceA);
serviceC.dependesOn(serviceA);
serviceD.dependesOn(serviceB);
serviceD.dependesOn(serviceC);
```

Now, **A** is a "grand-parent" of **D** in two ways. So, if you call getCountOfDependencies() on **D**, it will count the direct parents (**B** and **C**) and will ask each of those to report their dependencies. They will each report 1, and thus **A** will be double-counted.

So, if you can have that type of situation, you will have to modify the approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the following should work.

Add an `ArrayList<String> dependentServices` as a class member.

Change `startService()` to `startService(String callerName)`.

When starting a service, for example serviceA, call `serviceA.startService(serviceName);`

In your startService(...) method add the following:

```
boolean dependent = false;

for(int i = 0; i < dependentServices.size(); i++) {

    if(dependentServices.get(i).equals(callerName) {
        dependent = true;
    }
}

if(!dependent) {
    dependentServices.add(callerName);
}
```

In each service, the ArrayList dependentServices will now keep a list of the names of the services which have called it. The size of the ArrayList will tell you how many services there are.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a StaticCounter class and use that for identifying counts by incrementing the values.

StaticCounter.java

```
public class StaticCounter {
  static int COUNTER;
}
```

JTry.java

```
public class JTry {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
      System.err.println("Passing checkpoint " + StaticCounter.COUNTER++);
    }
  }
```